# How do I invoke a MethodCall with another MethodCall on the first MethodCall's first argument?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am attempting to implement this:

```
@Override // java.util.Function
public Object apply(final ThingWithParameters thing) {
  return bozo(thing.getParameters());
}
private Object bozo(final Object[] parameters) {
  // Use magic ByteBuddy stuff to "spread" the parameters out
  return this.object.baz(parameter0, parameter1); // ...where these are the first two parameters in the array
}
```

I've tried:

```
builder = builder
  .defineMethod("bozo" ...)
  .implement(MethodCall.invoke(bazDescription)
             .onField(thisObjectFieldDescription)
             .withArgumentArrayElements(0, 2))

  .implement(parameterizedTypeFunctionThingWithParametersObject) // Function<ThingWithParameters, Object>
  .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(bozoDescription) // implement apply(ThingWithParameters thing): call bozo()...
             .withMethodCall(MethodCall.invoke(getParametersMethodDescription) // ...with the result of invoking getParameters()...
                             .onArgument(0))); // ...on thing (except see below)
```

…but this does not work.  The error message is deeply weird and leads me to believe that argument `0` is not referring to `thing`, but to something else entirely (maybe the receiver type somehow?).  Here is a snippet from the stack:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke public java.lang.Object[] com.foo.ThingWithParameters.getParameters() on java.util.function.Function<? super V, ? extends com.foo.ThingWithParameters>
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$TargetHandler$ForMethodParameter$Resolved.toStackManipulation(MethodCall.java:2530)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$Appender.toStackManipulation(MethodCall.java:3548)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$ArgumentLoader$ForMethodCall.toStackManipulation(MethodCall.java:1687)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$Appender.toStackManipulation(MethodCall.java:3545)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$Appender.apply(MethodCall.java:3509)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyCode(TypeWriter.java:708)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:693)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:600)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:5660)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:2166)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:232)
```

Note that while my proxy class does in fact implement `Function`, it actually implements `Function<ThingWithParameters, Object>`.  And, I never define `V`.  I'm assuming ByteBuddy does this internally somewhere.

What is the recipe I should be using?

Comment: Weirdly, I can make this stack oddness go away if, instead of using `implement(type)` followed immediately by `.intercept(...)`, I define the `apply` method manually.  I'm guessing that `implement` generates a `Function` internally to implement the interface and that may be the source of the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Function` class defines multiple methods, some of them as default methods. Byte Buddy will attempt to implement all those methods by your `Implementation` where it works for the `apply` method but fails for others. Therefore, rather define an explicit matcher to indicate the method you'd like to implement.

Comment: Ahhhhh, yes, of course; I always think of `Function` as just defining `apply` but of course that is not the case! Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I've fallen for this too many times now :) Same holds for all the Java 8 functional interfaces. Rafael - you could change one of the BB examples to use `Function` and add a clear comment on why `named("transform")` is needed :)